# how to update a variable in a text file

Tags: python, file, variables, python-3.x

I have a program that opens an account and there are several lines but i want it to update this one line `credits = 0` Whenever a purchase is made I want it to add one more to the amount this is what the file looks like

```
['namef', 'namel', 'email', 'adress', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone', 'phone 2']

credits = 0
```

this bit of info is kept inside of a text file I don't care if you replace it (as long as it has 1 more) or whether you just update it. Please help me out :) sorry if this question is trival

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: You need to copy the **relevant** piece of code in your question. And you might want to change your save format, for example use JSON (module json) for easier data handling

Comment: I tried 
`for line in file:
    if line == "credits":
        a = line.split('=')
        b = int(a)
        writelines(b+1)
`

Comment: The issue is I dont have any code to do this I dont know how to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code snippet should give you an idea on how to go about. This code updates, the value of the counter variable present within a file **counter_file.txt**

```
import os

counter_file = open(r'./counter_file.txt', 'r+')
content_lines = []

for line in counter_file:
        if 'counter=' in line:
                line_components = line.split('=')
                int_value = int(line_components[1]) + 1
                line_components[1] = str(int_value)
                updated_line= "=".join(line_components)
                content_lines.append(updated_line)
        else:
                content_lines.append(line)

counter_file.seek(0)
counter_file.truncate()
counter_file.writelines(content_lines)
counter_file.close()
```

Hopefully, this sheds some light on how to go about with solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can create a general text file replacer based on a dictionary containing what to look for as keys and as corresponding values what to replace:

In the template text file put some flags where you want variables:

```
['<namef>', 'namel', 'email', 'adress', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone', 'phone 2']

credits = <credit_var>
```

Then create a mapping dictionary:

```
map_dict = {'<namef>':'New name', '<credit_var>':1}
```

Then rewrite the text file doing the replacements:

```
newfile = open('new_file.txt', 'w')
for l in open('template.txt'):
    for k,v in map_dict.iteritems():
        l = l.replace(k,str(v))
    newfile.write(l)
newfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating new files like new_file.txt or template.txt, you can use your existing file. Here I am using `client_name` and `client_credit_score` as place holders reflecting user data:

```
client_name="Joseph"
client_credit_score=1

map_dict = {'<namef>':f'{client_name}', '<credit_var>':f'{client_credit_score}'}
template = """['<namef>', 'namel', 'email', 'adress', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone', 'phone 2']    
credits = <credit_var>"""

with open('existing_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k,v in map_dict.items():
      template = template.replace(k,str(v))
    f.write(template)
```

Here the `existing_file.txt` will have this code initially (like you question):

```
['namef', 'namel', 'email', 'adress', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone', 'phone 2']
credits = 0
```

And thanks to the `map_dict`, all the keys will be updated with new values in your file. Here's what output will look like:

```
['Joseph', 'namel', 'email', 'adress', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone', 'phone 2']
credits = 1
```

Note: Special thanks to @Saullo and @Tarun for the above answer.